# How to set database for project used on multiple sub-domains and which technology is the best to use?

Tags: javascript, php, database, settings, project

I'm trying to start developing a large web project that should be used on multiple sub-domains where the sub-domain represents the client. I'm facing the problem, that I don't know the best or recommended solution for this type of project.

The project (THE LOGIC) should be something like slack.com. Sub-domain represents the client (clientAlpha.slack.com, clientBeta.slack.com, etc.). The problem is, that I can imagine multiple solutions and all of them has many disadvantages.

All data will be stored on my server - client only do the registration

1. How to organize DB structure for multiple clients?

   - Each client has own database  named with some prefix. But there is a problem with some kind of "super db" that causes a need for multiple-db connection. Multiple DBs = ugly job during DB structure update.
   - One DB with some "super-tables" and many same tables for each client. I this this is the ugliest solution. Same structure-update problem as above.
   - "Normal" DB with "normal" tables where the client is represented by foreign_key. This solution impacts the speed of DB.
2. Which type DB is best to use? I mean are there any limitations for number of data (rows)? I have good practices with MySQL and MongoDB. No GPS, no blobs - only "pure" data will be stored in tables (numbers, strings, booleans, texts)
3. Is it still common to use PHP for server or PHP is dead for new project creation? /Or is good to use JavaScript (node.js)?

I tried to find some information abou this, but thousand people = thousand opinions :/

Thank you for your guidance and recommendation.

Comment: *"Is it still common to use PHP for server or PHP is dead for new project creation?"*. PHP is very much alive and it is the best language ever...

Comment: @Dharman Thank you. I have to change my friends :)

Comment: Why do people keep hating on PHP, I just seen a post where a Python user claimed PHP was stale outdated language, however PHP has proper type restrictions, something Python is a bit lacking in.... anyway.  Im not bashing Python, I don't know python, but people that don't know modern PHP shouldn't bash it either.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes, to much for a comment:

- An open database connection can access not only the default database. Use `datbase.table` to access other databases.
- Use either different (and unique) prefixes, or different databases. Don't mix them.
- If using different databases, use one special database for global data (your super-tables).
- There are always database limits. Best is to estimate your requirements, multiply them by 10 and look into the database descriptions. Anyway, most disk and memory space are the limits.
- Make a clean database layout with optimal members (e.g choose `smallint` if you only store values between 0 and 1000), create schematics for you database access to determine the keys. Do both before starting with the implementation.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Open db connection...oookey I'm dumb. Prefixes - is it really good idea (a need of DB structure change)?